# Connecting to a server using UDP

Tags: c++, linux, shell, ubuntu

> You are asked to develop a Floppy Disk Shell environment that allows users to access a floppy disk mounted on a remote computer. Your Floppy Disk Shell would give use an illusion that s/he is operating on a locally mounted floppy disk.
>
> Required Modules:
>
> Server daemon: a single threaded UDP Floppy Disk server, which accepts three API commands:
>   Request for new connection.
>   Request for data in a specific sector of the floppy disk.
>   Request for disconnect.
>   The server daemon should be able to handle up to 4 clients at the same time. If the 5th client tries to connect, it will be rejected.
>
> Upon a successful connection, the client will receive a handle from the floppy server and use the handle as the reference in all future remote requests.
>
> When a connected client requests for data or disconnection, the floppy daemon must check whether the client's handle is consistent with its port number and inet address associated. If not, the request will be rejected

Am not asking any one to solve it am just asking if some one can provide with some useful links that I can read cause I dont have any clue where to start ... so if someone could tell where to start from I will be thankful :)

Answer (score 0):

[Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) is an often linked site. If it's good or not I can't say.

Myself I learned network programming the hard way, before there were any tutorials on the web, by reading a lot of code, manual pages and references. And most important of all, doing lots of experimentation.